# Collisions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

In my code I am detecting collisions between a box and the balls, but as soon as the first collision occurs the console shows the following error:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"

What is the error in my code? What is the meaning of the displayed error?

```js
// Creating code for multiple balls as well as record the movement of the player

var canvas, cxt, h, w, n = 10,
    i, mousePos;
var ball = []; // Empty array
var p = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  length: 30,
  breath: 30,
  color: 'black'
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.querySelector('#style');
  cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
  h = canvas.height;
  w = canvas.width;
  ballType(n);
  // Add a mousemove event listener to the canvas
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoved);
  main();
}

function mouseMoved(evt) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  // Necessary work in the canvas coordinate system
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function movePlayerWithMouse() {
  if (mousePos !== undefined) {
    p.x = mousePos.x;
    p.y = mousePos.y;
  }
}

function ballType(n) {
  var cl = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange', 'pink', 'cyan', 'grey', 'pink'];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var e = Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
    f = {
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      radius: 5 + (30 * Math.random()), // Radius will be between 5 and 35
      a: -5 + (10 * Math.random()), // Value of a will be between -5 and 5
      b: -5 + (10 * Math.random()), //value of b will be between -5 and 5
      color: cl[e]
    }
    ball.push(f);
  }
}

function main() {
  cxt.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  player(p);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    draw(ball[i]);
  }
  var l = 0
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    move(ball[i], l);
    l++;
  }
  movePlayerWithMouse();
  count();
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

function draw(d) {
  cxt.save();
  cxt.translate(0, 0);
  cxt.fillStyle = d.color;
  cxt.beginPath();
  cxt.arc(d.x, d.y, d.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  cxt.fill();
  cxt.restore();
}

function move(m, index) {
  m.x += m.a;
  m.y += m.b;
  check(m);
  testCollision(m, index);
}

function check(m) {
  if ((m.x + m.radius) > w) { // Collision with the right wall
    m.a = -m.a;
    m.x = w - m.radius;
  } else if ((m.x - m.radius) < 0) { // Collision with the left wall
    m.a = -m.a;
    m.x = m.radius;
  }
  if ((m.y + m.radius) > h) { // Collision with the top wall
    m.b = -m.b;
    m.y = h - m.radius;
  } else if ((m.y - m.radius) < 0) { // Collision with the bottom surface
    m.b = -m.b;
    m.y = m.radius;
  }
}

function player(p) {
  cxt.save();
  cxt.translate(0, 0);
  cxt.fillStyle = p.color;
  cxt.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.length, p.breath);
  cxt.restore();
}

// For testing the collision

function test(rx, ry, rw, rh, cx, cy, cr) {
  var x0 = cx;
  var y0 = cy;
  if (x0 < rx) {
    x0 = rx;
  }
  if (x0 > (rx + rw)) {
    x0 = rx + rw;
  }
  if (y0 < ry) {
    y0 = ry;
  }
  if (y0 > (ry + rh)) {
    y0 = ry + rh;
  }
  return (((cx - x0) * (cx - x0) + (cy - y0) * (cy - y0)) < (cr * cr));
}

function testCollision(v, index) {
  if (test(p.x, p.y, p.breath, p.length, v.x, v.y, v.radius)) {
    ball.splice(index, 1); // Splice starts deleting the elements of array from the index given in the first parameter
    // and the second parameter accepts the number of array elements to be deleted
  }
}

function count() {
  cxt.save();
  if (ball.length == 0) {
    cxt.fillText("You win", 20, 20);
  } else {
    cxt.fillText(ball.length, 20, 20);
  }
  cxt.restore();
}
```

```css
#style {
  border: 2px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<body onload='init();'>
  <div>
    <canvas id='style' height='400' width='400'>
      Your browser does not support canvas...
    </canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The error says that you try to read "x" of an undefined value. `undefined.x`. You need to look for your `.x` code parts and check if any of the objects are undefined.

Comment: For me the error message is `TypeError: m is undefined` ;)

Comment: Typical case of changing the iterable while iterating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your code as you are removing the object from `array`, but not reducing the `n` so just update the following:

```
function testCollision(v, index) {
  if (test(p.x, p.y, p.breath, p.length, v.x, v.y, v.radius)) {
    ball.splice(index, 1);
    n--;
    // Splice starts deleting the elements of array from the index given in the first parameter
    // and the second parameter accepts the no. of array elements to be deleted
  }
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Bone mistakenly not formatted. Thanks for edit.

Comment: This, by itself, will not fix the fundamental issue. The iteration in `main` is `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { move(ball[i], l); //[...]`, but `move` may change the `ball` array. This can lead to skips aswell as to the mentioned issue of out of bounds. You fix the out of bounds issue, but not the potential skips. As a general hint for OP, if you are not absolutely sure what you are doing, don't change iterables while iterating.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes the run should be with array.length but when you are new to something you should be seeing that the approach which you took must run perfectly first then try improving the code.

Comment: @Harsh Pleasure is all mine.

Comment: To elaborate this further: the issue is he is looking e.g. at index 5, that removes index 5 from `balls`, now the previous index 6 is index 5, but his `i` advances to index 6. He will never consider the original index 6.